# Fantasy book with magical tattoos

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book where two main characters have got magical tattoos. One guys name is Will and a girl by the name of Jess.

Comment: Not much to go on.  Can you add any other details?  Any of the plot or setting?  When did you read it?

Answer (score 7):

### Could this be *[Clockwork Angel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003UYURXS)?*

[image]

This book is the first in *The Infernal Devices*, one of the various sub-trilogies set in the Shadowhunters universe.

- Most of the main characters are Shadowhunters, or Nephilim. They have runes inscribed on their skin (which look very like tattoos, and are referred to thus by the unenlightened throughout the series).
- Two of the main characters are **Will** Herondale and **Jess**amine Lovelace. The latter is certainly called Jessie at various points in the books, and probably Jess. It is also possible that you are thinking of Jem Carstairs, another character.

Comment: Nice. I actually read this, but I'd forgotten about the tats. Guess I didn't find it that memorable...